# Skining/Theming MVC 3 Application

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, styles

I am creating a web application in ASP.NET MVC 3 and SQL Server 2008. 
We want to allow our clients to choose their own styles for branding purposes.

Ideally, we would like them to choose from size, font and color attributes for the main html tags (h1, p, anchor, etc).

We were thinking about a form where users could choose size, font and color from drop downs for each of the supported tags and save this to a database. When this form was saved, we would save the entire style string in a field and return that as CSS file on the page.

The downfall with this approach is that when a user comes back in to edit these settings later, we will have to do some serious regex to get the attribute values and show them in the form again.

Any ideas on how best to implement this?

Thanks in advance,
Viper.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152682/user-generated-custom-css ?

Comment: @Major Byte - I dont think they are similar. My question is regarding how to store CSS in the database and match saved CSS back to the form again later for editing. While the question you linked seems to ask what is the best way to serve the sylesheet to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a better approach would to be to store each of the fields individually (either set the table up to have a field for each property or do a massive key-value pair setup) so that getting the data back out for changing is far easier (as the combining for the css on the fly is far easier than deconstructing it for editing)

Comment: cheers for the response. I was thinkg that but it sounds very messy. Any thoughts on storing the data as a JSON object?

Comment: Might be a possible way (that or having it as XML) but you'd be creating some wasted space with the JSON/XML definitions that would be duplicated accross multiple rows.