# Dynamic SASS generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, multi-tenant

I am working on a multi tenant app where I'd like each Tenant to control the colors of specific elements.  For example, I'd imaging have a form w/ color pickers where users could control items such as site background color, navbar colors, etc.

I have a baseline SASS(.scss) file which sets the default color scheme.  My questions are:

1. How would I then load the "dynamic" theme .scss file?
2. If I had model fields like Tenant.nav_bar_link_color, how would I load those values into the SASS theme file?
3. Would I be able to/should I somehow precompile the Tenant specific themes into the asset pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I think the method outline here makes most sense:

[User generated custom css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152682/user-generated-custom-css)

Basically i'll store the Tenant controlled CSS values in the DB, and then render them out in the head as overrides against my default SASS file....

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to the body element of the main application.  This could be like

```
<body class="">
```

Then programmatically add a class such as "scheme-red" or "scheme-blue" to this body element based on their selection of a theme.

In your SASS you would then have different color schemes that override the defaults.